# How to use elements in list by order

Tags: python, json, csv

My goal is to change multiple csv files in a folder into JSON.

First, I needed to list my csv files

```
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/folder_to_csv"):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
    #check if csv files are listed correctly
    print(os.path.join("C:/Users/folder_to_csv", filename))
```

With this, I was able to call csv files in that folder.
Result:
`C:/Users/folder_to_csv\file_1.csv   C:/Users/folder_to_csv\file_2.csv   C:/Users/folder_to_csv\file_3.csv`

Then, I wanted to use all of the csv files in 'csvlist' to `jsonObj`, however for some reason, my codes are only using the first file (C:/Users/folder_to_csv\file_1.csv)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import json
import csv
import requests
import threading
import os


for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/folder_to_csv"):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        csvlist = os.path.join("C:/Users/folder_to_csv", filename)


data = {}   


def main():
    #loop csv list so my codes can read all csv files
    length = len(csvlist)
    for i in range(length):
        i += 1        
        path = csvlist
    
   #switch csv to json
    with open(path, mode='r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        processdata = [row for row in reader]


    dlist = processdata
    jsonObj = json.dumps(dlist) 


    })
    print(jsonObj)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the initial loop, you keep redefining the csvlist variable. I suppose you want it to be a list? Then just create an initial empty list and append to it instead of redefining

```
csvlist = []
...
csvlist.append(os.path.join("C:/Users/folder_to_csv", filename))
```